# Webpack does not process pug files from template in controller

Tags: angularjs, webpack, pug-loader

I recently updated an AngularJS (v1) project from Webpack v1 to v2 and TypeScript v1 to v2. The project uses pug files for generating the views, and prior to the upgrade there were no problems.

Since the upgrade, pug files that are referred in a controller no longer are processed by Webpack. Pug files specified in any routes are still working fine.

My `webpack.common.config.js` has pug configured with the pug-loader:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.pug$/,
      use: ['pug-loader']
    },
  ]
}
```

An example of a pug file that does not get processed anymore by Webpack.

```
this.$mdDialog.show({
  clickOutsideToClose: true,
  template: require('../components/ui/client.pug'),
  controller: ['$mdDialog', '$state', '$rootScope', 'clientService', ProfilePopupController],
  controllerAs: 'dm',
  bindToController: true,
  locals: { localData: popupData }
})
```

I attempted to explicitly refer to the pug-loader by using

```
template: require('pug-loader!../components/ui/client.pug');
```

This matches the example in the pug-loader documentation at the [Github pug-loader repository](https://github.com/pugjs/pug-loader)

```
template = require("pug-loader!./file.pug");
```

This gives me the error:

`ERROR in ./~/pug-loader!./src/app/components/ui/client.pug
Module build failed: Error: C:\Users\User\git\myapp\node_modules\pug-loader\index.js!C:\git\myapp\src\app\components\ui\client.pug:4:1`

I have a Github with a small application showing the problem. It's at [MyApp Repository](https://github.com/focher/myapp). If you build this app, you can see the template pug file referenced in the main.controller.ts `aboutPopup()` displays the partially processed code. Once built, go to Main and click the About button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution through some digging. By switching from `pug-loader`, which apparently doesn't automatically find pug references inside controllers, to `pug-html-loader` this was a key step. I had tried this before but just got unprocessed HTML so gave up on it.

Then I found a reference to adding `html-loader` as a second loader. So now I've changed my config in the `rules` section to:

```
{
  test: /\.pug$/,
  use: [
    'html-loader',
    'pug-html-loader'
  ]
}
```

This let everything process and build fine.